# Extending the TreeView control for incremental filtering/searching

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to extend the winforms TreeView control to allow incremental filtering and searching similar to the Solution Explorer in VS2012/VS2013.

Ideally, I would like it to be capable of replacing the existing TreeView with minimal code change - as far as the consumer is concerned, the only difference would be a method `void Filter(string)`.  Because of this, I think it would make sense for the `Nodes` property to return the `TreeNodeCollection` with ALL nodes, even ones not showing because of an applied filter.

I have the code written to handle the filtering, and it actually works quite well except when I access `base.Nodes`, it returns my filtered nodes and not the full list.

The problem I have is, I'm unable to clone or create a new instance of `TreeNodeCollection`, because the constructor is marked as internal.  So my ideal code would look something like this:

```
public class TreeViewEx : TreeView
{
    // results in a compiler error:
    private TreeNodeCollection _allNodes = new TreeNodeCollection();

    public new TreeNodeCollection Nodes { get { return _allNodes; } }

    public TreeNodeCollection FilteredNodes { get { return base.Nodes; } }

    public void Filter(string searchString)
    {
        base.BeginUpdate();
        base.Nodes.Clear();
        foreach (TreeNode node in FilterInternal(_allNodes, searchString))
        {
            base.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
        base.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I'm trying to decouple the nodes that are shown in the UI from the nodes that the consumer would access.  Of course with `TreeNodeCollection` having an internal constructor only, I'm unable to create a new instance or clone it.

I considered these two options, but neither sound like good solutions:

1. Use reflection to instantiate the `TreeNodeCollection` object (due to the internal constructor) for the second list.  This option seems like it would be more efficient than #2, but of course I'm creating an instance of an object I'm not supposed to.
2. Instantiate a second TreeView in memory and use the Nodes property from that to maintain my second list.  This seems like it might be a lot of overhead.

I want the end result to still be a `TreeNodeCollection` so the TreeView can be used to replace our existing controls with minimal code and we do have several places using the `Find` method, which doesn't exist in `List<TreeNode>`.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to handle this?  What about performance/resource-wise with my two considerations?

Thank you

Update 1:

Per Pat's recommendation, I decided to take a step back and avoid messing with `Nodes` altogether.  So now I've added a `List<TreeNode> AllNodes` property and have the `Nodes` just display the nodes that appear in the TreeView (the filtered list), so now it's a bit simpler.

My problem now is, how do I know when `AllNodes` has an item added to it so I can keep `Nodes` in sync?  I've considered using a `BindingList` so I have the `ListChanged` event, but then I would need to have my TreeNode and node's children/grand-children/etc (`AllNodes[0].Nodes`) use a custom class that inherits from `TreeNode` and change the `Nodes` property, and `TreeNode.Nodes` isn't overridable.  Is there another way?  I could make a new property called NodeExs or something, but that seems very unintuitive and I could see another dev coming along later and pulling his hair out because the Nodes property is there but doesn't work.

Comment: You could clone the tree and remove the ones not wanted the assign it back to the treeview.

Comment: @terrybozzio thanks for your response.  The problem is, the `TreeNodeCollection` can't be Cloned because of the internal constructor.  I could stick it in a `List<TreeNode>`, but that has some other hurdles to overcome...

Comment: Unrelated: There's a reason Visual Studio abandoned archaic winforms and was rewritten in WPF. You can do this with [maximum performance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA) in WPF with 2 lines of code without resorting to any horrible hacks and without subclassing the standard TreeView.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your proposed solutions,  #2 is out because a `TreeNode` cannot belong more than one control. And while it might be possible to create an instance of `TreeNodeCollection` via reflection, it won't be very useful because its designed to be coupled to a `TreeView` or another `TreeNode`. You won't be able to add/remove nodes from the collection.

> Because of this, I think it would make sense for the Nodes property to
>   return the TreeNodeCollection with ALL nodes, even ones not showing
>   because of an applied filter.

I disagree, the `TreeNodeCollection` returned by the `Nodes` property is used by the framework and OS to render the control. You really don't want to hide this property or alter its functionality.

If a consumer needs to have access to `_allNodes`, create a `List<TreeNode> AllNodes` property or use a custom collection.

Comment: Pat, thanks for the response.  I believe using the Clone method I can clone a node and reattach it to a new parent, can't I?  I'm beginning to think that using your AllNodes approach might be the right way to go.  This mainly started out as me questioning whether or not this could be done - and then being determined to get it to work.  At this point, refactoring the existing code would have been quicker, but I feel like I'm on a mission now ...

Comment: @AdamPlocher We've all been there. Going on little tangents like this can be fun and often rewarding. To answer your question, yes you can clone the node and add it to another control, in your case a dummy 'TreeView'. But what does that get you? The node will be bound to the dummy TreeView - effectively making the 'TreeNodeCollection' nothing more than an expensive 'ICollection' that dispatches Win32 messages every time you add or remove an item.

Comment: Thanks Pat, right, that's exactly what I was concerned with, too.  Would you mind taking a look at the update at the bottom of my question?  I tried the AllNodes approach but I'm not sure how to keep the base.Nodes in sync with AllNodes.  Thanks

Comment: @AdamPlocher I would add 'AddNode(TreeNode node)' and 'RemovedNode(TreeNode node)' methods to your 'TreeView' and update 'Nodes' and 'AllNodes' on each invocation. Then I would use comments to instruct your consumers to use these methods not the 'AllNodes' and 'Nodes' properties to add/remove nodes.

Comment: @AdamPlocher If your going to stick with the winforms TreeView, then any solution is going to be a compromise. It might be worth taking a look at [TreeViewAdv](http://sourceforge.net/p/treeviewadv/wiki/Home/) It supports incremental search. I'm not sure about filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that the `TreeNodeCollection` should only be used to read the listed nodes. Instead, I've used `List<TreeNode>` to list nodes. In my project, I created a `List<TreeNode>` for each level on the `TreeView`. I filled the lists at the same time when I filled the `TreeView`, at the startup. In the end, I used `AddRange()` to make and combine a list of the all nodes. This way I had all the nodes listed and categorized.

It's easy and fast to create this kinds of lists. I also created a `List<string>` version of the all nodes list, which I set up as an `AutoCompleteCustomSource` for my `TextBox`. This way I was able to use `TextBox` with `AutoComplete` for searching the nodes.

I'd make different lists for the consumers and other categories. Then I'd only add the items to the `TreeView` which meet the given criteria. You can also use `treeView.Nodes.Remove()` to remove any nodes. You'd still have the actual node stored on the lists, and could add it back again later.

These are just some ideas.